# Error authenticating with OAuth in Python

Tags: python, api, oauth, calendar

I'm trying to learn how to utilize OAuth for an application I'm developing, and I can't seem to wrap my head around the verification code part and the point of a redirect URI. Here's what I have.. I don't understand the point of a redirect URI, and once I do get a valid verification code. How would I even go about pulling in calendar events from Google for the user in JSON?

```
from pyoauth2 import Client

CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
REDIRECT_URL = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'

client = Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            site='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1',
            authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

print '-' * 80
authorize_url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL, scope=SCOPE)
print 'Go to the following link in your browser:'
print authorize_url

code = raw_input('Enter the verification code and hit ENTER when you re done:')
code = code.strip()
access_token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL)
print 'token', access_token.headers

print '-' * 80
print 'get user info' 
ret = access_token.get('/userinfo')
print ret.parsed
```

Oops.. forgot the error.. I'm not even sure what a verification code should look like.

```
token {'Authorization': 'Bearer '}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
get user info
{u'error': {u'code': 401, u'message': u'Invalid Credentials', u'errors': [{u'locationType': u'header', u'domain': u'global', u'message': u'Invalid Credentials', u'reason': u'authError', u'location': u'Authorization'}]}}
```

Comment: You said it causes an error- what error? Could you post the traceback?

Comment: Added it! Sorry 'bout that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you might consider giving [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth) a try. Rauth is a simple consumer client for OAuth 1.0/a, 2.0, and Ofly. While I don't have an example for Google immediately available, you could checkout the [example scripts](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples) on GitHub to see how you might go about using it. In particular, the Facebook example should be a very similar flow. Feel free to contact me if you need more detailed help.